# Explanation of solr max score

Tags: solr

When I choose to view the score field in solr results I see the score assigned by solr to every document returned and a maxscore value that is the score of the topmost returned document.

I need to know is there a cut-off to the solr score or not. I mean if the maxscore is 6.89343 or 2.34365, so does this mean that it is 6.89343 of 10 as the final score? or how can I decide that I'm close to the most correct result.

If possible, I need a simple explanation of the scoring algorithm used by solr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maxscore is the scoring of the topmost document in the search results.
There is no cutoff for the maxscore, and depends upon the scoring calculations and normalization done by Lucene/Solr.

The topmost document would have the maxscore, while you would get an idea from the scores of the documents below it, as to how off they are from the topmost.

For Scoring explaination you can check [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201008.mbox/%3CAANLkTi=JPph3X5TLkbJ_rax5qhEx6zRcgUiuNhQBF4xu@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed a z-score from a normal distribution then you can calculate the CDF (as it appears [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201008.mbox/%3CAANLkTi=JPph3X5TLkbJ_rax5qhEx6zRcgUiuNhQBF4xu@mail.gmail.com%3E) ). The CDF will give you a bounded score from 0 to 1. Its hard for me to interpret what the CDF really means in this case given the un-normalized score is calculated in several steps, but you can sort of think of it as the probability that you got the right answer as long as your collection is well populated with the relevant material.